# json output in foreach order by timestamp

Tags: php, json

I have json file like below

```
{
  "api": {
    "results": 1,
    "predictions": [
      {
        "match_winner": "N 2",
        "under_over": "-3.5",
        "goals_home": "-1.5",
        "goals_away": "-1.5",
        "advice": "Combo Double chance :  draws or Pafos and -3.5 goals",
        "winning_percent": {
          "home": "10%",
          "draws": "45%",
          "away": "45%"
        },
        "teams": {
          "home": {
            "team_id": 3398,
            "team_name": "Doxa",
            "last_5_matches": {
              "forme": "13%",
              "att": "33%",
              "def": "33%",
              "goals": 3,
              "goals_avg": 0.6,
              "goals_against": 6,
              "goals_against_avg": 1.2
            },
            "all_last_matches": {
              "matchs": {
                "matchsPlayed": {
                  "home": 14,
                  "away": 14,
                  "total": 28
                },
                "wins": {
                  "home": 5,
                  "away": 2,
                  "total": 7
                },
                "draws": {
                  "home": 6,
                  "away": 4,
                  "total": 10
                },
                "loses": {
                  "home": 3,
                  "away": 8,
                  "total": 11
                }
              },
              "goals": {
                "goalsFor": {
                  "home": 15,
                  "away": 11,
                  "total": 26
                },
                "goalsAgainst": {
                  "home": 14,
                  "away": 21,
                  "total": 35
                }
              },
              "goalsAvg": {
                "goalsFor": {
                  "home": "1.1",
                  "away": "0.8",
                  "total": "0.9"
                },
                "goalsAgainst": {
                  "home": "1.0",
                  "away": "1.5",
                  "total": "1.3"
                }
              }
            },
            "last_h2h": {
              "played": {
                "home": 5,
                "away": 4,
                "total": 9
              },
              "wins": {
                "home": 2,
                "away": 1,
                "total": 3
              },
              "draws": {
                "home": 2,
                "away": 0,
                "total": 2
              },
              "loses": {
                "home": 1,
                "away": 3,
                "total": 4
              }
            }
          },
          "away": {
            "team_id": 3403,
            "team_name": "Pafos",
            "last_5_matches": {
              "forme": "73%",
              "att": "89%",
              "def": "56%",
              "goals": 8,
              "goals_avg": 1.6,
              "goals_against": 4,
              "goals_against_avg": 0.8
            },
            "all_last_matches": {
              "matchs": {
                "matchsPlayed": {
                  "home": 15,
                  "away": 13,
                  "total": 28
                },
                "wins": {
                  "home": 8,
                  "away": 1,
                  "total": 9
                },
                "draws": {
                  "home": 4,
                  "away": 5,
                  "total": 9
                },
                "loses": {
                  "home": 3,
                  "away": 7,
                  "total": 10
                }
              },
              "goals": {
                "goalsFor": {
                  "home": 28,
                  "away": 5,
                  "total": 33
                },
                "goalsAgainst": {
                  "home": 17,
                  "away": 12,
                  "total": 29
                }
              },
              "goalsAvg": {
                "goalsFor": {
                  "home": "1.9",
                  "away": "0.4",
                  "total": "1.2"
                },
                "goalsAgainst": {
                  "home": "1.1",
                  "away": "0.9",
                  "total": "1.0"
                }
              }
            },
            "last_h2h": {
              "played": {
                "home": 4,
                "away": 5,
                "total": 9
              },
              "wins": {
                "home": 3,
                "away": 1,
                "total": 4
              },
              "draws": {
                "home": 0,
                "away": 2,
                "total": 2
              },
              "loses": {
                "home": 1,
                "away": 2,
                "total": 3
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "h2h": [
          {
            "fixture_id": 123220,
            "league_id": 449,
            "league": {
              "name": "1. Division",
              "country": "Cyprus",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/318.png",
              "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/cy.svg"
            },
            "event_date": "2018-12-02T14:00:00+00:00",
            "event_timestamp": 1543759200,
            "firstHalfStart": 1543759200,
            "secondHalfStart": 1543762800,
            "round": "Regular Season - 11",
            "status": "Match Finished",
            "statusShort": "FT",
            "elapsed": 90,
            "venue": "Makario Stadium",
            "referee": "Giorgos Nicolaou, Cyprus",
            "homeTeam": {
              "team_id": 3398,
              "team_name": "Doxa",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3398.png"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
              "team_id": 3403,
              "team_name": "Paphos",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3403.png"
            },
            "goalsHomeTeam": 3,
            "goalsAwayTeam": 2,
            "score": {
              "halftime": "1-1",
              "fulltime": "3-2",
              "extratime": null,
              "penalty": null
            }
          },
          {
            "fixture_id": 123284,
            "league_id": 449,
            "league": {
              "name": "1. Division",
              "country": "Cyprus",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/318.png",
              "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/cy.svg"
            },
            "event_date": "2019-02-23T15:00:00+00:00",
            "event_timestamp": 1550934000,
            "firstHalfStart": 1550934000,
            "secondHalfStart": 1550937600,
            "round": "Regular Season - 22",
            "status": "Match Finished",
            "statusShort": "FT",
            "elapsed": 90,
            "venue": "Stelios Kyriakides Stadium",
            "referee": "Konstantinos Photiou, Cyprus",
            "homeTeam": {
              "team_id": 3403,
              "team_name": "Paphos",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3403.png"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
              "team_id": 3398,
              "team_name": "Doxa",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3398.png"
            },
            "goalsHomeTeam": 1,
            "goalsAwayTeam": 0,
            "score": {
              "halftime": "0-0",
              "fulltime": "1-0",
              "extratime": null,
              "penalty": null
            }
          },
          {
            "fixture_id": 123137,
            "league_id": 449,
            "league": {
              "name": "1. Division",
              "country": "Cyprus",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/318.png",
              "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/cy.svg"
            },
            "event_date": "2019-03-09T17:00:00+00:00",
            "event_timestamp": 1552150800,
            "firstHalfStart": 1552150800,
            "secondHalfStart": 1552154400,
            "round": "Relegation Round - 2",
            "status": "Match Finished",
            "statusShort": "FT",
            "elapsed": 90,
            "venue": "Makario Stadium",
            "referee": "Giorgos Nicolaou, Cyprus",
            "homeTeam": {
              "team_id": 3398,
              "team_name": "Doxa",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3398.png"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
              "team_id": 3403,
              "team_name": "Paphos",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3403.png"
            },
            "goalsHomeTeam": 0,
            "goalsAwayTeam": 0,
            "score": {
              "halftime": "0-0",
              "fulltime": "0-0",
              "extratime": null,
              "penalty": null
            }
          },
          {
            "fixture_id": 123153,
            "league_id": 449,
            "league": {
              "name": "1. Division",
              "country": "Cyprus",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/318.png",
              "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/cy.svg"
            },
            "event_date": "2019-04-20T16:00:00+00:00",
            "event_timestamp": 1555776000,
            "firstHalfStart": 1555776000,
            "secondHalfStart": 1555779600,
            "round": "Relegation Round - 7",
            "status": "Match Finished",
            "statusShort": "FT",
            "elapsed": 90,
            "venue": "Stelios Kyriakides Stadium",
            "referee": "Chrysovalantis Theouli, Cyprus",
            "homeTeam": {
              "team_id": 3403,
              "team_name": "Paphos",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3403.png"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
              "team_id": 3398,
              "team_name": "Doxa",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3398.png"
            },
            "goalsHomeTeam": 3,
            "goalsAwayTeam": 2,
            "score": {
              "halftime": "2-1",
              "fulltime": "3-2",
              "extratime": null,
              "penalty": null
            }
          },
          {
            "fixture_id": 216438,
            "league_id": 786,
            "league": {
              "name": "1. Division",
              "country": "Cyprus",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/318.png",
              "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/cy.svg"
            },
            "event_date": "2019-12-01T15:00:00+00:00",
            "event_timestamp": 1575212400,
            "firstHalfStart": 1575212400,
            "secondHalfStart": 1575216000,
            "round": "Regular Season - 11",
            "status": "Match Finished",
            "statusShort": "FT",
            "elapsed": 90,
            "venue": "Stadio Stelios Kyriakides",
            "referee": "V. Demetriou",
            "homeTeam": {
              "team_id": 3403,
              "team_name": "Paphos",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3403.png"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
              "team_id": 3398,
              "team_name": "Doxa",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3398.png"
            },
            "goalsHomeTeam": 0,
            "goalsAwayTeam": 1,
            "score": {
              "halftime": "0-0",
              "fulltime": "0-1",
              "extratime": null,
              "penalty": null
            }
          },
          {
            "fixture_id": 216504,
            "league_id": 786,
            "league": {
              "name": "1. Division",
              "country": "Cyprus",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/318.png",
              "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/cy.svg"
            },
            "event_date": "2020-02-29T15:00:00+00:00",
            "event_timestamp": 1582988400,
            "firstHalfStart": 1582988400,
            "secondHalfStart": 1582992000,
            "round": "Regular Season - 22",
            "status": "Match Finished",
            "statusShort": "FT",
            "elapsed": 90,
            "venue": "Makareio Stadio",
            "referee": "K. Christodoulou",
            "homeTeam": {
              "team_id": 3398,
              "team_name": "Doxa",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3398.png"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
              "team_id": 3403,
              "team_name": "Paphos",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3403.png"
            },
            "goalsHomeTeam": 0,
            "goalsAwayTeam": 4,
            "score": {
              "halftime": "0-1",
              "fulltime": "0-4",
              "extratime": null,
              "penalty": null
            }
          },
          {
            "fixture_id": 331798,
            "league_id": 786,
            "league": {
              "name": "1. Division",
              "country": "Cyprus",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/318.png",
              "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/cy.svg"
            },
            "event_date": "2020-03-09T17:00:00+00:00",
            "event_timestamp": 1583773200,
            "firstHalfStart": 1583773200,
            "secondHalfStart": 1583776800,
            "round": "Relegation Round - 1",
            "status": "Match Finished",
            "statusShort": "FT",
            "elapsed": 90,
            "venue": "Makareio Stadio",
            "referee": "L. Soteriou",
            "homeTeam": {
              "team_id": 3398,
              "team_name": "Doxa",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3398.png"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
              "team_id": 3403,
              "team_name": "Pafos",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3403.png"
            },
            "goalsHomeTeam": 2,
            "goalsAwayTeam": 0,
            "score": {
              "halftime": "0-0",
              "fulltime": "2-0",
              "extratime": null,
              "penalty": null
            }
          },
          {
            "fixture_id": 369155,
            "league_id": 786,
            "league": {
              "name": "1. Division",
              "country": "Cyprus",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/318.png",
              "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/cy.svg"
            },
            "event_date": "2020-04-11T00:00:00+00:00",
            "event_timestamp": 1586563200,
            "firstHalfStart": null,
            "secondHalfStart": null,
            "round": "Relegation Round - 6",
            "status": "Match Cancelled",
            "statusShort": "CANC",
            "elapsed": 0,
            "venue": null,
            "referee": null,
            "homeTeam": {
              "team_id": 3403,
              "team_name": "Pafos",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3403.png"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
              "team_id": 3398,
              "team_name": "Doxa",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3398.png"
            },
            "goalsHomeTeam": null,
            "goalsAwayTeam": null,
            "score": {
              "halftime": null,
              "fulltime": null,
              "extratime": null,
              "penalty": null
            }
          },
          {
            "fixture_id": 570497,
            "league_id": 2658,
            "league": {
              "name": "1. Division",
              "country": "Cyprus",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/318.png",
              "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/cy.svg"
            },
            "event_date": "2020-11-29T14:00:00+00:00",
            "event_timestamp": 1606658400,
            "firstHalfStart": 1606658400,
            "secondHalfStart": 1606662000,
            "round": "Regular Season - 12",
            "status": "Match Finished",
            "statusShort": "FT",
            "elapsed": 90,
            "venue": "Stadio Stelios Kyriakides",
            "referee": "K. Fellas",
            "homeTeam": {
              "team_id": 3403,
              "team_name": "Pafos",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3403.png"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
              "team_id": 3398,
              "team_name": "Doxa",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3398.png"
            },
            "goalsHomeTeam": 2,
            "goalsAwayTeam": 0,
            "score": {
              "halftime": "0-0",
              "fulltime": "2-0",
              "extratime": null,
              "penalty": null
            }
          },
          {
            "fixture_id": 570588,
            "league_id": 2658,
            "league": {
              "name": "1. Division",
              "country": "Cyprus",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/318.png",
              "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/cy.svg"
            },
            "event_date": "2021-02-16T15:00:00+00:00",
            "event_timestamp": 1613487600,
            "firstHalfStart": 1613487600,
            "secondHalfStart": 1613491200,
            "round": "Regular Season - 25",
            "status": "Match Finished",
            "statusShort": "FT",
            "elapsed": 90,
            "venue": "Makareio Stadio",
            "referee": "C. Theouli",
            "homeTeam": {
              "team_id": 3398,
              "team_name": "Doxa",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3398.png"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
              "team_id": 3403,
              "team_name": "Pafos",
              "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/3403.png"
            },
            "goalsHomeTeam": 0,
            "goalsAwayTeam": 0,
            "score": {
              "halftime": "0-0",
              "fulltime": "0-0",
              "extratime": null,
              "penalty": null
            }
          }
        ],
        "comparison": {
          "forme": {
            "home": "15%",
            "away": "85%"
          },
          "att": {
            "home": "27%",
            "away": "73%"
          },
          "def": {
            "home": "40%",
            "away": "60%"
          },
          "fish_law": {
            "home": "67%",
            "away": "33%"
          },
          "h2h": {
            "home": "38%",
            "away": "62%"
          },
          "goals_h2h": {
            "home": "25%",
            "away": "75%"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want echo h2h fixerid from it and want sort by event_timestamp. I am new in PHP and trying from last 2 hours but its not working

My PHP code is like below

```
$json = file_get_contents("679812.json");
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$h2h = $data['api']['predictions'][0]['h2h'];
print_r($h2h);

usort($h2h, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['event_timestamp']) - strtotime($b['event_timestamp']); });

foreach($h2h as $row)
{
    echo $row['fixture_id'] ."\n";
}
```

its giving one by one error me. I am not able to achieve my goal. Anyone here can please help me for do it?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. when you use `json_decode`() with `true` as the second parameter, your result will all be associative array. And you reference an array with bracket []. So to get to `h2h`, you will have to look at the data's structure and reference it correctly.

```
$h2h = $data['api']['predictions'][0]['h2h'];
```

Once you got `$h2h` you can sort it with your `usort()` but just reference them as array.

```
usort($h2h, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['event_timestamp']) - strtotime($b['event_timestamp']);
 });
```

And also when you print out, you reference them as array.

```
foreach($h2h as $row)
{
    echo $row['fixture_id'] ."\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi!
Thanks, Its giving me error like  Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\json\index.php on line 10 on return strtotime($a['event_timestamp']) - strtotime($b['event_timestamp']); }); this line

Comment: are you able to print out $h2h? before usort() run print_r($h2h);

Comment: No, Its not printing that as well!

Comment: I have updated my code as per your answer!

Comment: what about print_r($data)? print_r($data['api']) and so on... I suspect that it isn't what you've given me.